# SQLite: Cannot batch CREATE and INSERT INTO?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm looking at ways to create update/patch files for a SQLite database that I'm writing, where you'd have `Version1.sql` or `Version20.sql` and it would apply all of the SQL in the file to the current database. These files would be a mix of commands -- creating tables and inserting into them or updating or deleting.

However, I'm running into a problem seemingly from the start:

```
CREATE TABLE db_version (
    version_number INT
);

INSERT INTO db_version ( version_number)VALUES (0);
```

In MySQL, this would work fine; but when I try to run them in SQLiteStudio, it fails immediately and tells me that `db_version` doesn't exist and so the `INSERT` statement is invalid. *Obviously, it doesn't exist.*

When I run the commands individually, they execute correctly and without errors. What am I missing about SQLite that makes it different from MySQL in that I'm not able to execute this?

Comment: Off the top of my head, perhaps the `CREATE TABLE` command has not been committed when that `INSERT` happens.

Comment: I think it is just SQLIteStudio quirks. If you put this statement into SQLite Manager (Firefox addon) it works

Comment: [Works for me](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d7e16/1).

Comment: SQLiteStudio - by default - executes only single query at the time. The one currently under the insertion cursor (or closest to the cursor). It even selects executed query, so you know what exactly got executed. You can either select everything you need to execute and then hit "execute", or you can switchi default behavior in options to always execute all contents of the editor window.